# Angular How to remove selected option from dropdown and put it back after removing it

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dropdown

I have a dropdown with a few select-options. If I select one of them a tag appears. Everything works fine but after choosing an option, I'd to remove if from the dropdown list because it's already selected. After changing my mind and deleting existing tag, I would like to have that option back to my dropdown to be able to select it again. Could anyone tell me how can I achieve it with Angular, please?
[image]

```
<select class="form-control" id="{{labelFilter | removewhitespaces}}" name="{{labelFilter | removewhitespaces}}"
    [(ngModel)]="defaultSelectedValue"
    (change)="selectedOption($event.target['value'])">
<option [value]="null" disabled selected>{{labelFilter}}</option>
<option *ngFor="let option of inputOptions | async"
        [value]="option | json">{{option.label}}</option>
```

```
 <tag-input *ngIf="filteredProperty.filters.length"
       [(ngModel)]="filteredProperty.filters"
       [class.full-width]="filteredProperty.filters.length"
       (onRemove)="setDefaultOptionSelect()"
       [identifyBy]="'name'"
       [displayBy]="'label'"
       [placeholder]="''"
       [secondaryPlaceholder]="''">
</tag-input>

export class SelectWithTagInputComponent {

@Input() filteredProperty: EnumRowConfigDto
@Input() inputOptions: Observable<IOption[]>
@Input() labelFilter: string
defaultSelectedValue = null

constructor() {
}

selectedOption(value): void {
    let filterData
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        filterData = JSON.parse(value)
        filterData['name'] = filterData['value']
        delete filterData['value']
    } else {
        filterData = value
    }
    this.addSelectedOptionToTagsArea(this.filteredProperty.filters, filterData)
}

addSelectedOptionToTagsArea(options, option): EnumDto {
    return options.findIndex(el => el.name === option.name) === -1 ? options.push(option) : options
}

setDefaultOptionSelect(): void {
    this.defaultSelectedValue = null
}
}
```

Comment: So you need two methods for example, one for removing one option from options list and one for inserting one option to options list. Am i right?

Comment: Create a pipe that takes the list of selected options and hides them from the list: `<option *ngFor="let option of inputOptions | async | hideSelectedOptions:  selectedOptions"`

Comment: How can I hide options with a pipe?

Comment: https://danielk.tech/home/angular-how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor#custom-filter-pipe